# How can I access target of my main/original project from Podfile's post install hook?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ruby, cocoapods

I have not find the according attribute in installer class from source code of Cocoapods, only like 'pod_targets' to access generated pods project. So what is the correct direction to it.

Comment: Provide more details what are you trying to achieve, perhaps there's a better way to do it.